# Praw AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_comments'

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I wrote a simple script for identifying users who contribute to certain subreddits. As a disclaimer, if you plan on using this code you should be sure to anonymize the data (as I will, by aggregating data and removing all usernames). It works with certain subreddits but does not seem to be very robust, as seen by the following error I get when I run it with /r/nba:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_comments'

Below is my code:

```
import praw
import pprint
users = [] #[username, flair, comments]

r=praw.Reddit(user_agent="user_agent")
r.login("username", "password")
submissions = r.get_subreddit('nba').get_top(limit=1) #won't work with higher limit?
for submission in submissions:
    submission.replace_more_comments(limit=3, threshold=5)
    flat_comments = praw.helpers.flatten_tree(submission.comments)
    for comment in flat_comments:
        user_comments = []
        for i in comment.author.get_comments(limit=2):
            user_comments.append(i.body)
            #user_comments.append(str(i.body)) #sometimes causes an error as well
        users.append([str(comment.author), comment.author_flair_text, user_comments])

pprint.pprint(users)
```

When I change the subreddit to 'python' it seems to encounter less problems, so hopefully someone can point out what I'm missing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you see the line

```
for i in comment.author.get_comments(limit=2):
```

I presume your code is failing because

```
comment.author is None
```

Comment: I dont see how it would be working in some instances but not in others.. in other words, why would a comment sometimes not have an author?

Comment: Why not try having a little play to see if you can pin down these cases. This is what I do if I get stuck. You can try a little for loop like for for comment in flat_comments: if comment.author is None: print comment Maybe this will be revealing

Comment: "why would a comment sometimes not have an author?" Perhaps because the author has deleted their account?

Comment: that was a great suggestion - turns out your line revealed a comment body of 'deleted' and author None.

Thanks a ton!